# Accessing Resource Files in MVC 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, resources

I want to to access key/value pair from my resource files in java script and .cshtml views.
For some static content on my cshtml i don't want to create a property in my model so it would be nice if i could directly access resource files.

Answer (score 15):

You can create a resx file and set its properties to [**public**, as described here](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/05/20/aspnet-mvc-globalizationlocalization.aspx).

Then on your `cshtml` you can use:

```
@Resources.ResNameHere.Property
```

To use on javascript simply render it on a `script` block

```
<script>
    var stringFromResource = "@Resources.ResNameHere.Property";
</script>
```

You can also implement an extension method to `Html` and read the resource from anywhere, even database if you need.

```
public static MvcHtmlString Resource<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, string key)
{
    var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(Website.Resources.ResNameHere));

    var val = resourceManager.GetString(key);

    // if value is not found return the key itself
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(String.IsNullOrEmpty(val) ? key : val);
}
```

Then you can call as

```
@Html.Resource("Key")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the resource from a Razor view via the generated proxy class. Is that not working for you?

Comment: Not sure about this.could you please shed some more light on it. my resource files are in App_GlobalResources Folder.

Comment: Could you provide more information? What files do you have in your App_GlobalResources folder, how are you trying to access the resources, and what kind of failure are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the following situation when we want to access key/value pair from the resource files in JavaScript and .cshtml views.

### Inside .cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Contact", null, null, null, new { id = "general", Href = "#", @Newtitle = @Resources.General.Newtitle })
```

where the resource file is containing following data

```
Name      Value
----      -----
Newtitle  New title Value
```

Now you are ready to use your resource data

### Inside JavaScript

```
$('#general').click(function (evt) {
    alert($(this).attr("Newtitle"));
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks.